# QuickFix how to not send resend request?

Tags: quickfix

I need to know how we can restrict sending a "Resend Request". I'm copying the logs below. It appears that the "Resend Request" is being send from QuickFixEngine dll since we have not written any code for initiating a resend request. Please help me to solve how restrict a resend request. Also it appears that the MsgSeqNum is in correct order. Your help will be appreciated greatly.

8=FIX.4.29=5735=034=9949=UATENV52=20120717-16:31:28.29656=TRDUAT10=243

8=FIX.4.29=5835=049=TRDUAT56=UATENV52=20120717-16:28:34.24834=11910=029

8=FIX.4.29=37635=849=TRDUAT56=UATENV52=20120717-16:28:41.00434=12050=CBOEO57=Test_Trader37=1120716000006003150=139=120=060=20120717-16:28:40.00040=254=138=10442=2654=1167=OPT55=IBM44=-0.5077=O202=180.00201=1200=201207205=2121=359=01=TestAcct10115=USD14=56=0.50198=12280400019882=N17=071710150000128151=576=INCA30=CBOE75=2012071732=531=0.5011=82184825010=144
8=FIX.4.29=37935=849=TRDUAT56=UATENV52=20120717-16:28:41.00534=12150=CBOEO57=Test_Trader37=1120716000006004150=139=120=060=20120717-16:28:40.00040=254=238=20442=2654=2167=OPT55=IBM44=-0.5077=O202=185.00201=1200=201207205=2121=359=01=TestAcct10115=USD14=106=0.50198=12280400019882=N17=071720150000129151=1076=INCA30=CBOE75=2012071732=1031=0.5011=82184825010=036

8=FIX.4.29=6935=234=10049=UATENV52=20120717-16:31:35.50056=TRDUAT **7=120** **16=0** 10=230

8=FIX.4.29=37635=849=TRDUAT56=UATENV52=20120717-16:28:41.00534=12250=CBOEO57=Test_Trader37=1120716000006005150=139=120=060=20120717-16:28:40.00040=254=138=10442=2654=3167=OPT55=IBM44=-0.5077=O202=190.00201=1200=201207205=2121=359=01=TestAcct10115=USD14=56=0.50198=12280400019882=N17=071710150000130151=576=INCA30=CBOE75=2012071732=531=0.5011=82184825010=145

8=FIX.4.29=37935=834=12149=TRDUAT50=CBOEO52=20120717-16:28:41.00556=UATENV57=Test_Trader1=TestAcct1016=0.5011=82184825014=1015=USD17=07172015000012920=021=330=CBOE31=0.5032=1037=112071600000600438=2039=140=244=-0.5054=255=IBM59=060=20120717-16:28:40.00075=2012071776=INCA77=O150=1151=10167=OPT198=1228040001200=201207201=1202=185.00205=21442=2654=29882=N10=036

8=FIX.4.29=37635=834=12249=TRDUAT50=CBOEO52=20120717-16:28:41.00556=UATENV57=Test_Trader1=TestAcct1016=0.5011=82184825014=515=USD17=07171015000013020=021=330=CBOE31=0.5032=537=112071600000600538=1039=140=244=-0.5054=155=IBM59=060=20120717-16:28:40.00075=2012071776=INCA77=O150=1151=5167=OPT198=1228040001200=201207201=1202=190.00205=21442=2654=39882=N10=145

8=FIX.4.29=40735=849=TRDUAT56=UATENV52=20120717-16:28:41.444122=20120717-16:28:41.00443=Y34=12050=CBOEO57=Test_Trader37=1120716000006003150=139=120=060=20120717-16:28:40.00040=254=138=10442=2654=1167=OPT55=IBM44=-0.5077=O202=180.00201=1200=201207205=2121=359=01=TestAcct10115=USD14=56=0.50198=12280400019882=N17=071710150000128151=576=INCA30=CBOE75=2012071732=531=0.5011=82184825010=145

8=FIX.4.29=41035=849=TRDUAT56=UATENV52=20120717-16:28:41.444122=20120717-16:28:41.00543=Y34=12150=CBOEO57=Test_Trader37=1120716000006004150=139=120=060=20120717-16:28:40.00040=254=238=20442=2654=2167=OPT55=IBM44=-0.5077=O202=185.00201=1200=201207205=2121=359=01=TestAcct10115=USD14=106=0.50198=12280400019882=N17=071720150000129151=1076=INCA30=CBOE75=2012071732=1031=0.5011=82184825010=028

8=FIX.4.29=40735=849=TRDUAT56=UATENV52=20120717-16:28:41.444122=20120717-16:28:41.005

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you will get a resend request when reconnecting after a disconnect.  It is important to make sure that you haven't missed any messages.

If you want to avoid it, you need to edit the quickfix [config](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html#Session) and set ResetOnLogon Logoff and disconnect to Y.  That way it will not try to resend messages each time it disconnects.

I don't think this is a particularly good idea. You could miss messages.  Why is the resend request a problem for you?

Comment: Actually the firm we are going to send orders asked us not to send any "ResendRequest". I do think this is not a good idea.. Anyways we have to listen what the firm is asking..

Comment: you might want to not resend any orders that are old and you don't want to be executed - how would you achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore ResendRequests (i.e you don't want to resend any messages) the correct way in FIX to do this is by responding with a SequenceReset.

You can achieve this in QuickFix be overriding the `toApp()` method and throwing a `DoNotSend` exception.

QuickFix will generate the correct SequenceReset response based on the ResendRequest that was issued.

Here's an example:

```
8=FIX.4.29=9135=234=349=MY-INITIATOR-SERVICE52=20160418-09:11:20.69456=MY-ACCEPTOR-SERVICE7=216=510=133
8=FIX.4.29=12435=434=243=Y49=MY-ACCEPTOR-SERVICE52=20160418-09:11:20.69756=MY-INITIATOR-SERVICE122=20160418-09:11:20.69736=2123=Y10=068
```

Comment: how to find out if it's a resend flow from the toApp method. The SessionId and Message objects don't seem to have any info/current-seq-number for that?